# Synchronize script method with the help of another method

Tags: javascript

i have 2 scripts

```
script1(){
   // takes very long time
}


script2(){
   // takes less time
}
```

i want to synchronize these method but with the help another method...
cannot modify script1 and script2..

Answer (score 0):

In JS no two scripts can run in parallel! Therefore there is no need of syncing. If your methods use callbacks, then the callback would be a synchronization point.